# apache proxyremote and http

Tags: apache-2.2, proxy, mod-proxy

`ProxyRemote` syntax is:

```
<remote-server> = <protocol>://<hostname>[:port]
```

So, I have to put protocol before hostname.

But my proxy server is `x.y.z.n:1234` (without `http`)

And when I use proxyremote in this way, it doesn't work. (nothing happens)

```
ProxyRequests On
ProxyRemote http http://x.y.z.n:1234
```

If I remove `http://` from proxy url, Apache returns an error:

```
ProxyRemote: Bad syntax for a remote proxy server
```

How to resolve it?

Thanks.

Comment: how about just ProxyRequests On
ProxyRemote http://x.y.z.n:1234

Comment: @Rikih: `ProxyRemote takes two arguments, a scheme, partial URL or '*' and a proxy server`

Comment: Which protocol you use to communicate with your proxy?  If it's HTTP, `ProxyRemote * http://x.y.z.n:1234` should work